# Clean way to get value from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this string `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/`

I would like to extract the value after `pokemon/` in this case 6. This represent Pokémon ids which could span between 1 -> N

I know this is pretty trivial and was wondering a nice solution for future proofing. Here is my solution.

```
const foo= "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"
const result = foo.split('/') //[ 'https:', '', 'pokeapi.co', 'api', 'v2', 'pokemon', '6', '' ]
const ids = result[6]
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear; are you stuck on this somewhere? This seems pretty cut-and-dried. If you always want the item after "pokemon" you could use `result.indexOf("pokemon")+1`;

Comment: `Clear way` and `nice solution for future proofing` is really broad. What do you mean with **clear** and **future proof** e.g. does this mean that you want to verify that the domain is actually `pokeapi.co` and the path before the ID is `api/v2/pokemon/`?

Comment: @t.niese sorry for the confusion. I was just looking for a nice solution. You can ignore future proofing mention

Comment: _"nice"_ is also broad. For me a _"nice"_ solution would not just extract the id but also ensure that the rest of the URL is correct so that changes in the URL can be noticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the value after the last `/` character like so:

```
const pokemonID = foo.substring(foo.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

Using [String.lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to get the final index of the slash character, and then using [String.substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) with only a single argument to parse the part of the string after that last `/` character. We add 1 to the lastIndexOf to omit the final slash.

For this to work you need to drop your final trailing slash (which won't do anything anyways) from your request URL.

This could be abstracted into a utility function to get the last value of any url, which is the biggest improvement over using a split and find by index approach.

However, beware, it will take whatever the value is after the last slash.
Using the string `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/pokedex` would return `pokedex`.

If you are using Angular, React, Vue etc with built in router, there will be specific APIs for the framework that can get the exact parameter you need regardless of URL shape.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built-in URL API to do the splitting correctly for you:

```
const url = new URL("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/");
```

Then you can get the pathname and split that:

```
const path = url.pathname.split("/");
```

After you split it you can get the value `6` by accessing the 5th element here:

```js
const url = new URL("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/");

const path = url.pathname.split("/");

console.log(path[4]);
```

Comment: How is this different than simply splitting the string as originally suggested?

Comment: @user1599011 If the URL was something like `https:////...` then would it still work? No. URLs can come in a variety of ways. That's why I suggest using the built-in API to get the pathname for us.

Comment: The string could be different in many ways and the solution wouldn't work, but I don't think the fact that the string happens to be a URL is particularly relevant.

Comment: @user1599011 `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/%36/` and `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/` represent the same URL. With `new URL` you will get `6` in both cases. If you treat it as string you won't. So you either parse the URL using a proper API or you need to use `decodeURIComponent` if you initially treated it as a string (That's just one example).

Answer (score 1):

you could also do something like:

```
url.split('pokemon/')[1].split('/')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do

```
const result = new URL(url).pathname.split('/');
const id = result[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is better than yours

```
const foo= "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"
const result = foo.indexOf("pokemon/");
const id_index = result + 8
const id = foo[id_index];
```